# Extracting data from multiple files with python

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to extract data from a directory with 12 .txt files. Each file contains 3 columns of data (X,Y,Z) that i want to extract. I want to collect all the data in one df(InforDF), but so far i only succeeded in creating a df with all of the X,Y and Z data in the same column. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import fnmatch

path = os.getcwd()

file_list = os.listdir(path)

InfoDF = pd.DataFrame()

for file in file_list:
    try:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
            filedata = open(file, 'r')
            df = pd.read_table(filedata, delim_whitespace=True, names={'X','Y','Z'})

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: As a remark, do not catch Exception in general (always catch a particular type of exception)

Comment: You are overwriting df at each iteration

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.read_table(filedata, delim_whitespace=True, names={'X','Y','Z'})
```

this line replace `df` at each iteration of the loop, that's why you only have the last one at the end of your program.

what you can do is to save all your dataframe in a list and concatenate them at the end

```
df_list = []
for file in file_list:
    try:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'): 
            filedata = open(file, 'r')
            df_list.append(pd.read_table(filedata, delim_whitespace=True, names={'X','Y','Z'}))
df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

alternatively, you can write it:

```
df_list = pd.concat([pd.read_table(open(file, 'r'), delim_whitespace=True, names={'X','Y','Z'})  for file in file_list if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt')])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) for select all files, create list of `DataFrames` `dfs` in `list comprehension` and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
files = glob.glob('*.txt')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp, delim_whitespace=True, names=['X','Y','Z']) for fp in files]

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

- As camilleri mentions above, you are overwriting `df` in your loop
- Also there is no point catching a general exception

**Solution**: Create an empty dataframe `InfoDF` before the loop and then use [append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) or [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) to populate it with smaller `df`s

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import fnmatch

path = os.getcwd()

file_list = os.listdir(path)

InfoDF = pd.DataFrame(columns={'X','Y','Z'}) # create empty dataframe
for file in file_list:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'): 
        filedata = open(file, 'r')
        df = pd.read_table(filedata, delim_whitespace=True, names={'X','Y','Z'})
        InfoDF.append(df, ignore_index=True)
print InfoDF
```