# Initializing an empty DataFrame for dynamic allocation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal to initialize an empty dataframe and populate it row by row. Initially I do not know what are the row labels (`index`), and also I do not know what the `columns`  are. Also, the `index` can be multilevel.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

**Preferred method**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Demo data which will be used to populate the dataframe
my_list = [pd.Series(np.random.rand(10), index=np.arange(10)*1e-6) for i in range(5)]

# Demo indices which will be used to index the dataframe
id1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
id2 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
id3 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i1, i2, i3, s in zip(id1, id2, id3, my_list):
    df.loc[(i1, i2, i3), :] = s
```

And ofcorse this is not correct and throws me the error:

```
KeyError: "['a' 0.1 0] not in index"
```

**Current Approach**

Currently, the way I am solving this problem is that I know the columns labels will be the same for all rows, so once I read the first series, I know the labels for all series. Also, I know the index is three levels. So here is what I do:

```
df = None
idx = pd.MultiIndex(labels=[[], [], []], levels=[[], [], []], names=['id1', 'id2', 'id3'])

for i1, i2, i3, s in zip(id1, id2, id3, my_list):
    if df is None:
        df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, columns=s.index)
    df.loc[(i1, i2, i3)] = s
```

**Question**

What is the best way to approach this? Is it possible to remove the `if` statement inside the loop and the empty index declaration in the current method, so that it will be along the lines of the **preferred method**?

Answer (score 1):

I think better and faster is use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor with `my_list` and [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html), because `loops` in `pandas` are slow and best is avoid it:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([id1, id2, id3], names=['id1', 'id2', 'id3'])
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, index=mux)
print (df)
             0.000000  0.000001  0.000002  0.000003  0.000004  0.000005  \
id1 id2 id3                                                               
a   0.1 0    0.804894  0.121733  0.030610  0.084308  0.751264  0.542138   
b   0.2 1    0.868729  0.049293  0.679061  0.375005  0.281873  0.182111   
c   0.3 2    0.766086  0.779906  0.928323  0.724433  0.275672  0.279673   
d   0.4 3    0.656994  0.304625  0.430252  0.350452  0.558119  0.674358   
e   0.5 4    0.045430  0.371147  0.885556  0.318458  0.411363  0.419160   

             0.000006  0.000007  0.000008  0.000009  
id1 id2 id3                                          
a   0.1 0    0.941973  0.318702  0.060750  0.108110  
b   0.2 1    0.944578  0.839771  0.331519  0.973904  
c   0.3 2    0.373569  0.985934  0.855927  0.878398  
d   0.4 3    0.041317  0.900308  0.728050  0.897996  
e   0.5 4    0.312687  0.662131  0.034483  0.633083
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just as a follow up, I suppose I should have indicated in my question that for my actual data I must have a loop to go through the series, since I am reading them from a file (each series is read from an entry of HDF table). I used my_list just as a demo...

Comment: then better is append data from loop to list and last create `DataFrame` by `concat` - maybe help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39850990/2901002) answer.